# Errors when trying to access Editor method

Tags: python

s soon as I attempt to access any method for object "e" I get the error "AttributeError: instance has no attribute".  I'm assuming when I'm creating the object, I'm not doing it in the correct manner.  Does anyone know why?

```
import shapefile

sf = shapefile.Reader('C:/users/name/desktop/shapefiles/Polygon')
e = shapefile.Editor(shapefile = 'desktop/shapefiles/Polygon.shp')

indexesMpart = [i for i, shape in enumerate(shapes) if len(shape.parts) > 1]
for index in indexesMpart:
    e.field('something', fieldType = 'C', size = '4')
```

Comment: Where are you getting the error? What is the *exact* error?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\askdljfasd\Desktop\Python\multipart.py", line 9, in <module>
    e.field('something', fieldType = 'C', size = '4')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyshp-1.2.0-py2.7.egg\shapefile.py", line 944, in field
    self.fields.append((name, fieldType, size, decimal))
AttributeError: Editor instance has no attribute 'fields'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\something\Desktop\test2\testing.py", line 5, in <module>
    e = shapefile.Editor(shapefile = 'C:/Users/something/Desktop/test2/testing')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyshp-1.2.0-py2.7.egg\shapefile.py", line 1048, in __init__
    self.records = r.records()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyshp-1.2.0-py2.7.egg\shapefile.py", line 525, in records
    r = self.__record()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyshp-1.2.0-py2.7.egg\shapefile.py", line 490, in __record
    value = int(value)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '**********'
```

After evaluating the error and code of shapefile.py, the reason why the Editor object was returning the ValueError is because of Null attributes in the .dbf file associated to the .shp file.  A simple attribution of [0,1,2,3,4,5] for each item in my .shp file satisfies the constructor attempting to call the records method.

Thank you for your assistance Silas, wouldn't have been able to figure this out if not for your guidance.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the code of that module, the only way I can see (there's actually [a patch submitted](https://code.google.com/p/pyshp/issues/detail?id=29) for this) that you could end up with an `Editor` object without a `fields` attribute is if the conditional `if os.path.isfile("%s.shp" % base):` at line 1043 fails because it can't find a `.shp` file.  Are you sure your file exists and that you are initializing with the correct path and file name?

Comment: I am absolutely sure.  I am able to access the shape file using the Reader class

Comment: It is only when I create an object for the Writer or Editor class and attempt to call one of its methods do I get an error

Comment: Well, according to the code you copied here, you are opening the editor with a relative instead of absolute path.  Try using the absolute path instead.

Comment: That results in ValueError invalid literal for int() with base 10, doesn't make any sense.  That keyword argument should be accepting a string...

Comment: What argument did you pass, and what was the actual stack trace for the crash?  I'm betting your new error is a new problem caused by you passing a string for `size` instead of an integer.